# What is the best project structure for a vuejs + vuex + axios project (client side only)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm creating a project in vuejs + vuex + sequlize + axios.

I'm wondering what is the best structure for my project.

FYI I manage 2 different projects, 1 for the client side and one for the server side.

My Client side project structure:

```
/app/src: root app.vue, main.js, route.js

/src/assets: png,svg files
/src/components: subcomponents 
/src/helpers: consts, and other helpers
/src/mixins: 
/src/services: axios, 3rd parties services
/src/store: x.module.js, y.module.js...
/src/styles: general style.
/src/views: Viewed windows, components accesible for user.
```

I found this structure nice but not that good, a lot of logic storing in the store modules.

Do you have a better structure for my project?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you separate backend and frontend and consume the backend as a rest api. It is far more manageable and is scalable in the long term.

so I would

```
app/client/app.vue
app/server/server.js
```

Comment: Currently, I manage 2 different projects.
The structure you see above is only for client side

Comment: than you shouldn't have specified sequelize,

I suggest you use vue-cli or try nuxt and follow their structure.